# Powerline Networking - can I just add another adapter

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I currently have a pair of NETGEAR XAVB2001-100NAS Up to 200Mbps Powerline AV 200 Adapters. Can I just add a third unit upstairs (like http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122361, for example) and all three ports will have connectivity to each other?

Or do these guys work in pairs only?

Comment: Are you using them with a switch/router?

Comment: Yes. Both are plugged into separate routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I went and bought two more... and... it works a treat!

Shame the manufacturers don't make this clearer. I bet a lot of people simply don't realise this is even possible.

Comment: Was wondering this very question as well. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Can't vouch for Netgear but I have D-link powerline and three of the plugged in, works like a charm.